# saving large array as csv with different fomat

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which is of the size of 1000x1000. I want to save it as a CSV which can be done using:

```
numpy.savetxt('file.csv', array, delimiter = ',', fmt = '%d')
```

How can I save this array with only column 1 being `int32` and rest in `float`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fmt` parameter allows that:

```
fmt : str or sequence of strs, optional
    A single format (%10.5f), a sequence of formats, or a
    multi-format string, e.g. 'Iteration %d -- %10.5f', in which
    case `delimiter` is ignored. For complex `X`, the legal options
    for `fmt` are:
        a) a single specifier, `fmt='%.4e'`, resulting in numbers formatted
            like `' (%s+%sj)' % (fmt, fmt)`
        b) a full string specifying every real and imaginary part, e.g.
            `' %.4e %+.4j %.4e %+.4j %.4e %+.4j'` for 3 columns
        c) a list of specifiers, one per column - in this case, the real
            and imaginary part must have separate specifiers,
            e.g. `['%.3e + %.3ej', '(%.15e%+.15ej)']` for 2 columns
```

In your case, you can specify a sequence of formats:

```
numpy.savetxt('file.csv', array, delimiter = ',', fmt = ['%d'] + ['%.4f']*999)
```